# How to interactively authenticate the custom skills in Amazon Alexa without linking to any account?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm new to building the Alexa Skills. I have built one custom skill that written weather updates when someone asked like "Hey Alexa, Give me weather updates for zip code 75252". Now I want to authenticate this service. Whenever user invokes the skill, It should give a welcome message and ask for the pin. When the user responds with a valid pin then only he should allow accessing the weather updates.

I found capital one video with something similar I want to implement. 
[a youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKacMCPLMi0)

My customer skills invocation MyWeatherUpdate is A kind of conversion I want to implement is as follows:

Me: Hey Alexa, MyWeatherUpdate

Alexa: Wellcome user, Please say your pin

Me: Give me weather updates for zip code 75252

Alexa: Please say your pin to access this service

Me: Pin is 1234

Alexa: You have successfully validated your pin. Now you can check the weather updates

Me: Give me weather updates for zip code 75252

Alexa: Temperature is 82 degrees F.

My Current Code in Lambda in NodeJS:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
 switch(event.request.type){
        case 'LaunchRequest':
            onLaunch(event.request,
            event.session,
            (sessionAttributes, speechletResponse) => {
                callback(null, buildResponse(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse));
            });
            break;
        case 'IntentRequest':
            onIntent(event.request,
            event.session,
            (sessionAttributes, speechletResponse) => {
                callback(null, buildResponse(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse));
            });
            break;
        case 'SessionEndedRequest':
            onSessionEnded(event.request, event.session);
            callback();
            break;
    }
```

};

```
function onIntent(intentRequest, session, callback) {
console.log(`onIntent requestId=${intentRequest.requestId}, sessionId=${session.sessionId}`);
const intent = intentRequest.intent;
const intentName = intentRequest.intent.name;
switch(intentName) {
        case "MyNLG":
              getCompanyInfo(intent, session, callback);
              break;
        case "AMAZON.HelpIntent":
            getWelcomeResponse(callback);
            break;
        case "GoodByeNLG" :
            handleSessionEndRequest(callback);
            break;          
        case "WeatherUpdates" : 
            getWeatherUpdates(intent, session, callback);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error('Invalid intent');
    }
```

}

Can anyone please guide me any references to resolve this solution. I searched online but most of the link are related to linking with another app or purchase service using Alexa.

Comment: The `userId` available inside `context.System.user` [and several other places](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference#session-object) uniquely identifies the user.  What else do you need? Obviously, you'd need to track the PIN in a database.

Comment: I tried to store the user verfication as a boolean variable in session attribute after successful verification and checked this value for every intent request and it's working now. I;m getting a response as the way I have mentioned in the question but only in the Test section of Service Simulator of Alexa Skills. When I tried on Alexa device, It's saying "there is a problem with a requested skill response." Any idea on how can I debug this issue?

Comment: Try looking at the cloud watch